# How spectrogram decides time in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to use the function spectrogram over a signal that is 6h long. Unfortunately (I'm not getting the reason) matlab return a graph where the time is like 60 minutes. I'm trying to understand the principles that matlab uses for calculate x-axis, but I'm not able to succeed in my intention. Could anyone help me?

Comment: the x-axis measurement of a spectrogram is not minutes or hours, it's the a time measurement representing the time bins which you set for your Fourier Transform. If you do not understand it, try searching on Google first - we cannot help you on this.

Comment: Thank you, I solved the problem. Actually I've solved it partially. My signal was an HRV (Heart Rate Variability) sampled each second. In the documentation I found (probably I'm wrong) that Fs is, by default, equal to one. So I used spectrogram giving simply my signal. Unfortunately the time axis was wrongly interpreted by the code. Finally just setting Fs=1 everything worked. Time axis was correctly interpreted and the same was frequency range.

Comment: Considering that HRV has max freq at 0.5Hz (so sampling each second is ok) and that Fs=1 (default), i am not able to understand why the spectrogram was wrong.